# Why don't we need "the" in "from lack of sleep"?

Tags: articles

> From lack of sleep

Since we're talking about a specific lack, namely lack of sleep, it seems that the article *the* should be there.  That is,

> From the lack of sleep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare:

> I had been refreshing EL&U for 48 hours straight. I think that the lack of sleep was the cause of those hallucinations.
>
> Hallucinations are a common symptom of lack of sleep.

The first one regards a specific lack of sleep (definite article), while the second one regards lack of sleep in general (no article).

Comment: I find it perfectly natural-sounding and grammatical to flip the presence of *the* in your examples.  (Not that yours are wrong, just that I don't find them convincing support for your answer.)

Answer (score 6):

Thinking about it, I believe that the answer is that "lack of" is treated as a quantifier, like "lots of", "too much", or "three hours'". (This is from introspection, and I have no references for the analysis)

What is confusing is that "lack" may also function as a noun taking a complement "of sleep", so in that construction it can take an article "from a lack of sleep". (It would not take "the" because contra Anderson Silva, it is not specific: "of sleep" distinguishes it from other kinds of lack, but not from other individual lacks, I think).

Comment: Excellent, the quantifier explanation makes sense. Same thing would work with "tons of" or "loads of", though interestingly the same doesn't seem to apply to "deficit of".

Answer (score 1):

Agree with both these answers, but you seem to be at cross-purposes.  'Lack of' may refer to a specific shortage (taking 'the'), or to a more general lack (with 'a' or no article).  So may other qualifiers or quantifiers.

> What made me type "hte" was probably the lack of sleep (but may have been the four beers I had before logging on)
>
> What affects my typing most is a lack of sleep (though a keyboard I'm not used to doesn't help).
>
> I usually blame my bad typing on lack of sleep (though my friends say it's incompetence).